# How do I dynamically change the value of text in html whenever a python variable is changed using ajax?

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I'm using ajax, python, Django, HTML, and javascript for my project.

I'd like to know, if there is a p in my HTML file like,

```
<p class='text_box', id='tbox'>

    {{ text_variable_from_python }}

</p>

<input class='input_box', id='ibox', type='text'>
```

And if I'd input some text into the input box, make a simple ajax request with the "text" variable and get an output from the server, which I would update on the views.py as,

```
def main(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_text = request.POST['text']
        context = {'text_variable_from_python': new_text}

    else:
        context = {'text_variable_from_python': 'You can change me!'}

    print(context)
    return render(request, 'Main.html', context=context)
```

My question is, how do I send the data dynamically from **the server** to appear on **client's webpage** using ajax and python in between the two?

Using my method, I can only see "You can change me!" on the webpage or nothing at all. No matter how many differing prompts I give, further changes do not show on the webpage.

EDIT:
My ajax code for sending the variable.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function update_dialogue() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "json",
            url: "update_text",
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("tbox").value = data['text_variable_from_python'];
            }

        });

    }
```

My ajax code for recieving the variable.

```
<script>
  function getInputValue() {
    let inputVal = document.getElementById("ibox").value;
    document.getElementById("ibox").value = '';

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'main',
        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
               'text': inputVal,}
    });

  }
</script>
```

Comment: If you send a **GET** request from your Ajax call then it will give response *You can change me!* & if send **POST** then it'll send whatever it receved from your request. Provide your Ajax code

Comment: I've asked as you did and I've provided the code with an edit.